# Overflow scroll and nowrap unwanted scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a drop down menu which I'd like to have the text content control the width of. Sometimes this menu will have a `max-height` with a scroll-bar.

If you run the snippet below you'll see the last word of the longest piece of text will wrap due to the presence of the scroll-bar. Using `white-space: nowrap;` will cause the text to go underneath the y-scroll-bar an make an x-scroll-bar to appear.

What's the best way to make this work? There's plenty I could do with JS (detect width of the text and apply a width to the container etc) but looking for CSS only solutions.

```css
.drop-menu {
  postion: relative;
}

ul, il {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.drop-items {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.drop-items li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-menu">
  <span>Menu</span>
  <div class="drop-items">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item item item item item item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you interested in truncate the overflowing text with ellipsis `...`?¿

Comment: No the full text would have to display

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.drop-items { left: 0; right: 0; }`. Note, the width of the container will no longer decided by the content.

By the way you have a typo `postion`, which should be `position`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkhm92uj/)**

```css
.drop-menu {
  position: relative;
}
ul,
il {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.drop-items {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.drop-items li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-menu">
  <span>Menu</span>
  <div class="drop-items">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item item item item item last</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, just use some right padding, e.g. `.drop-items li { padding-right: 30px; }` to make the room for the horizontal scrollbar. According to [this article](http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php) - "on modern browsers generally the scrollbars are 17 pixels wide but I would still recommend that you continue to use 20 pixels as your spec when working on wireframes or creating mock-ups".

You can even do  `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;` if needed.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8jaxj81/)**

```css
.drop-menu {
  position: relative;
}
ul,
il {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.drop-items {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.drop-items li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-menu">
  <span>Menu</span>
  <div class="drop-items">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item item item item item last</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only valid answer that I see is the `padding-right` trick. Upvote for that